# PHP GET must be filtered?

Tags: php, sql

I have a page where variables are grabbed from the URL via `$_GET['page']`.

The question I have is, due to my page setup, is it necessary to filter this variable if it is only being used for a PHP switch to grab the page?
For example:

```
define('TAB_ID', 1100);
define('PAGE_ID', 5005);
define('TITLE','Goodies');
define('MAIN',true);
require_once "global.php";

if(!LOGGED_IN) {
    header("Location: ".WWW."/");
    exit;
}

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = "badges";
} else { 
    $page = clean($_GET['page']);
}

$core->Header(1);
$core->Header(2);

include(TEMPLATES.'/generic-top.php');

switch($page){
    default:
    case "badges": {
        include(TEMPLATES.'/goodies/badges.php');           
    }
}

include(TEMPLATES.'/footer.php');
```

I have a function named `clean()` which is used to clean the variable from exploits, however because this variable is not being used in queries of any kind, just for the `switch()`, is it necessary?

I'm not having any problems with the current setup, but I'm only curious.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The only thing I'd change here is the order of your `if/else` - it will read more easily if you test for the normal condition first, and you can then swap the clauses around. In other words `if (true) { a } else { b }` makes more sense than `if (!false) { b } else { a }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. In fact, sanitising could be harmful, if you happen to have a "page" that has an apostrophe in it, or whatever it is your `clean` function affects (your `switch` would fail)

What you have here is a whitelist. Anything that you haven't explicitly defined will be rejected.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it unnecessary, it's impossible. Your "clean" function, whatever it is, doesn't make sense and won't work. You can't magically filter or clean a value on input until you know how it's to be used. For example, a value to be sent to a database needs to be wrapped in quotes and for quote characters to be escaped, while a value to be output as text to an HTML page needs to be escaped with `htmlspecialchars()`, but there is no all-purpose way to clean a variable.

Comment: The function would be better named `paracetamoxyfrusebendroneomycin()`

Comment: Didn't realise you were a fan of "Amateur Transplants" Niet! - [paracetamoxyfrusebendroneomycin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlmEc8rd_Nw&feature=kp)